# (.Net) Optimal data structure to find union of words between a sentence and dictionary

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, full-text-search, lookup, string-search

I am trying to find the most optimal way to compare words in a collection (hashset, list) to a document (like an essay, blog) for finding matching words.

For example - I have the following collection of words

```
Old
Man
Lazy
Dog
```

and if the document on which I need to search is

`A dog is man's best friend`

The output should be

```
dog, man
```

It is possible that the document contains more than 1000+ words.

The most easiest approach will be the following where

```
HasSet {Collection} = {Old, Man, Lazy, Dog}

for each {word} in the {document}
    if the Collection contains {word}
       return {word}
    else
       continue
```

Is there a more efficient approach to perform the text search? Wouldn't a **suffix tree** be a overkill for this approach? The challenge I am having is that the input word document could be 1000-5000 words long and the collection is a list of 9000 words